# Can we enable VF page in a lightning component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-connect

Can we enable VF page in a lightning component. If possible provide me with suggestion how to achieve it.

Comment: please refer to the question i posted a while back http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54534/now-that-lightning-is-here-whats-the-future-of-visualforce-in-short-visual which talks about VF & Lightning. as of now VF & Lightning might not work with each other

Comment: You'd also help yourself a lot by going through the [Trailhead Lightning Components Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lightning_components) and reading the various docs and Developer Blogposts where examples are already given of how to use VF with Lightning.