# Visualforce Page in Lightning Design Example

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning

I'm pretty new to Salesforce, Lightning and the Visualforce coding. While it seems to be possible to code Visualforce Pages in Lightning design with JavaScript etc. I was curious if there is already a GitHub Repository maybe that provides an example page.

Doesn't have to be more than a couple input fields that looks exactly like the 'Record Details' Lightning component that contains all the fields assigned to an object.

Additionally, I was curious how I can retrieve the object ID from the URL with the new lightning way of doing it since the APEX classes are not supported yet.

I wouldn't mind going through a course / tutorial either but it's tough to find some good examples out there that represent the newest way of doing things.

Thank you

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/ - SLDS in visualforce is just CSS - and Here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147023/what-is-suggested-approach-to-transfer-vf-pages-to-be-lightning-ready/147026#147026

Comment: @Eric Thank you very much! I will work through it. When I just copy & paste the Visualforce page I receive an error currently.  Error: Field $SLDS does not exist. I'm sure I have to do some additional steps

Comment: Yea, the SLDS is a placeholder for your static resources containing the SLDS assets

Comment: @Eric Awesome, thank you very much! Just saw you created the template. Is it possible to contact you personally?

Comment: Also, the courses you seek are here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/

Comment: @Jaypi Unfortunately there is no contact mechanism on SFSE and I do not see any way to provide that where it would not be publicly available. The community here is amazing  provided you are willing to learn and give things a shot first.

Comment: @Eric Is it possible to format the same way as on the screenshot? I wasn't able to find it yet. http://imgur.com/YHFLSRW