# Modify the SFDC CSS without overriding pages

Tags: css, slds

Is it possible to override the system CSS so I don't have to update all of the visualforce pages?  I'm looking to apply to SLDS to all pages.

Comment: No. You'll have modify all of your pages.

Comment: Looksie here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147023/what-is-suggested-approach-to-transfer-vf-pages-to-be-lightning-ready - Otherwise what sfdcfox said