# Does <aura:application ... extends="ltng:outApp" /> stop the usability via /c/appName.app?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-out

Following the description [here to make an Lightning Component available in Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91674/showing-a-lightning-component-app-inside-visualforce-page), I found, that the Lightning App does no longer work as expected as a Standalone App via

```
/c/appName.app
```

The js code and the callouts seem to be happen, but the screen stays just empty. The reason is the presence of

```
extends="ltng:outApp"
```

Is that behavior intended this way, so that an app can only be used either **Standalone** OR **extending ltng:outApp** and never both at the same time?

Comment: A humble request, please write a blog describing your thoughts, best features, likes, dislikes about lightning if you find some time. A simple tutorial/ documentation on aura would make it very very helpful, there is no one i know of in this community who is extensively looking into aura as much as you.

Comment: Hi @Rao, if I find the time I will do that, promise ;-) ... meanwhile I would like to invite you and everyone here to this article http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96636/feature-matrix-comparision-lightning-components-vs-visualforce-now-and-roadma/96689#96689 - my idea is that we could collect our experience and findings about low-level facts together, since it's very time consuming to dig that out at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the contents of your ltng:outApp serve the single purpose of providing one or more  tags to inform Lightning Framework about the components and events you want to be able to use