# Display Current Logged in User Accounts

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am able to display current logged in user accounts using Lightning components.
But it is displaying empty list, when adding lightning component in a VF page(AccPage) and trying to access that page from another page(displayPage).

I think I need to pass parameter but i have no idea how to do that can anyone help me with this.

Here is my code

DISPLAY PAGE :

```
  <apex:page>
        <table align="top" float="right">
        <tr>

       <td Style="padding-right: 60px;"> <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="img">
 **<!-- Here I am giving Link for AccPage-->**
                        <a 
                            href="https://mylightpackage-dev-ed--mylightpackage5.na16.visual.force.com/apex/AccPage">
                            <img src="{!$Resource.Img1}" alt="Accounts"
                            class="imagestyleHomePage" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="desc">Accounts</div>    
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="img">
                        <a 
                            href="https://mylightpackage-dev-ed--mylightpackage5.na16.visual.force.com/apex/PageToShowCases">
                            <img src="{!$Resource.Img2}" alt="Cases"
                            class="imagestyleHomePage" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="desc">Cases</div>
                    </div>
                </td></tr>
                <tr>

        </table>
        </apex:page>
```

AccPage :

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false"  >
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:AccInfoApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:AccInfoComponent",
          { label : "" },
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller(AccountInfo) :

```
public class AccountInfo {
   @AuraEnabled
   public static List<Account> getAccounts() {
       ID contactId = [Select contactid from User where id =: Userinfo.getUserid()].contactId;

        ID AccID  = [Select AccountID from Contact where id =: contactid ].AccountId;
       List<Account> acc =[SELECT Id, name,AccountNumber,AnnualRevenue
       FROM Account where Id =: AccID];
       return acc;
   }

}
```

AccInfoComponent:

```
  <aura:component controller="AccountInfo">
   <aura:attribute name="accountRows" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <table align="left">

        <aura:iteration var="acc" items="{!v.accountRows}">
                    <tr class="border_bottom">
                        <td style="padding-right: 200px;">Account Name</td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 200px;"> {!acc.Name}       </td>
            </tr><hr class="hrcls"/>
            <tr>
                        <td>Account Number</td>
                        <td> {!acc.AccountNumber}  </td>
                    </tr><hr class="hrcls"/>
           </aura:iteration>
        </table>

  </aura:component>
```

AccInfoComponentHelper:

```
({
    getAllaccounts : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccounts");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a){
            component.set("v.accountRows", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: I think you missed few things,its mentioned [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91674/showing-a-lightning-component-app-inside-visualforce-page)